# Ansible not seeing ansible_eth1 device

Tags: ansible

Given this debug:

```
  - name: Display all variables/facts known for a host
    debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```

Producing, in part, this output:

```
ok: [ny2-uat-app02] => {
    "var": {
        "hostvars[inventory_hostname]": {
            ...
            "ansible_eth1": {
                "active": true,
                "device": "eth1",
                "ipv4": {
                    ...
                },
                "ipv6": [
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                ],
    ...
```

Why does this line in a template:

```
- seeds: "{% for host in groups['seeds'] %}{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_' + internode_interface]['ipv4']['address'] }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
```

Produce this error:

```
fatal: [ny2-uat-app02] => {'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute u'ansible_eth1'", 'failed': True}
```

The debug task runs right before the ansible task to process the template.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to add a new node to an existing cluster.

Comment: Won't this help facter_ipaddress ? In my case, one of the image was CentOS 6.5 and other was CentOS x.x (something else), using ansible_eth[1or5].ipv[4or6].ipaddress was available while gather_facts: True but in other VM, it was not populated (like in your case). I used facter_ipaddress and it worked.

Comment: @ArunSangal - Interesting, didn't know about that. Not sure when I'll get back around to trying this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you run `{% for host in groups['seeds'] %}`, a specific host can not access variables of other hosts in group `seeds`, so the task was fail.

To access variables of other hosts, you should enable [fact caching](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching).

In playbook files, you should adding `gather_facts: True` to update facts.

Comment: Do you enable fact caching?

Comment: I did, but the initial creation of the cluster was in one directory, and the files to create the additional node were in another directory. All because the vagrant command doesn't allow an input file to be specified. I copied .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/facts under the second directory, and was able to add the new node.

Answer (score 0):

One more reminder: do not limit the hosts in the ansible-playbook command to a specific host when that hosts needs variables form other hosts!

```
ansible-playbook -l 'node1' hosts.yml
```

can not find ansible_eth1 form other hosts from 'all' so should be

```
ansible-playbook hosts.yml
```